# Add_annotations plotly first and last datapoints

Tags: r, plotly

**My Main Goal:**

- Trying to add annotations to both the first datapoint of my
  scatterplot and the last datapoint of my scatterplot (the entries for
  years 2006 and 2021 respectively).

**My Secondary Goals:**

- If possible, it would also be helpful to find out how to select out
  specific datapoints to add annotations, as I only know the
  which.max/which.min functions so far.
- It would also be nice to know how to list the jobs on each point.

**My Dput:**

```
structure(list(Year = 2006:2021, Month_USD = c(1160L, 1240L, 
1360L, 1480L, 1320L, 1320L, 375L, 1600L, 2000L, 2000L, 1600L, 
2240L, 1900L, 2300L, 2900L, 2300L), Degree = c("High School", 
"High School", "High School", "High School", "High School", "High School", 
"High School", "High School", "High School", "BA", "BA", "BA", 
"BA", "BA", "M.Ed", "M.Ed"), Country = c("USA", "USA", "USA", 
"USA", "USA", "USA", "DE", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", 
"PRC", "PRC", "PRC", "HK"), Job = c("Disher", "Prep", "Prep", 
"Prep", "Prep", "Prep", "Au Pair", "CSA", "Valet", "Valet", "Intake", 
"CM", "Teacher", "Teacher", "Teacher", "Student"), Median_Household_Income_US = c(4833L, 
4961L, 4784L, 4750L, 4626L, 4556L, 4547L, 4706L, 4634L, 4873L, 
5025L, 5218L, 5360L, 5725L, NA, NA), US_Home_Price_Index = c(183.24, 
173.36, 152.56, 146.69, 140.64, 135.16, 143.88, 159.3, 166.5, 
175.17, 184.51, 195.99, 204.9, 212.59, 236.31, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))
```

**Current Scatterplot:**

```
pal <- c("Red", "Blue", "Green")

plot_ly(data = Earnings_Year, 
        x=~Year,
        y=~Month_USD,
        type='scatter',
        mode='markers',
        symbol = ~as.factor(Degree),
        symbols=c("star-open-dot","hexagon-open-dot","diamond-open-dot"),
        color = ~as.factor(Degree),
        colors = pal,
        hoverinfo="text",
        text= paste("Year: ",
                    Earnings_Year$Year,
                    "<br>", #this is a line break
                    "Monthly USD: ",
                    Earnings_Year$Month_USD),
        size=10) %>% 
        add_annotations(
          x=Earnings_Year$Year[which.min(Earnings_Year$Month_USD)],
          y=Earnings_Year$Month_USD[which.min(Earnings_Year$Month_USD)],
          text = "Au Pair Job in Germany") %>%
  add_annotations(
    x=Earnings_Year$Year[which.max(Earnings_Year$Month_USD)],
    y=Earnings_Year$Month_USD[which.max(Earnings_Year$Month_USD)],
    text = "Last Teaching Job in China") %>% 
  layout(legend= list(x=1,y=0.5),
         title="Earnings by Degree",
         xaxis=list(title="Year"),
         yaxis=list(title="Monthly USD"))
```

**Image of Current Scatter:**

[image: Scatter]

**Scatter That I Want:**

[image: Ref Graph]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Figured it out. Just needed to pipe additional add_annotations as well as just select specific values for x and y:**

```
pal <- c("Red", "Blue", "Green")

plot_ly(data = Earnings_Year, 
        x=~Year,
        y=~Month_USD,
        type='scatter',
        mode='markers',
        symbol = ~as.factor(Degree),
        symbols=c("star-open-dot","hexagon-open-dot","diamond-open-dot"),
        color = ~as.factor(Degree),
        colors = pal,
        hoverinfo="text",
        text= paste("Year: ",
                    Earnings_Year$Year,
                    "<br>", #this is a line break
                    "Monthly USD: ",
                    Earnings_Year$Month_USD),
        size=10) %>% 
        add_annotations(
          x=Earnings_Year$Year[which.min(Earnings_Year$Month_USD)],
          y=Earnings_Year$Month_USD[which.min(Earnings_Year$Month_USD)],
          text = "Au Pair Job in Germany") %>%
  add_annotations(
    x=Earnings_Year$Year[which.max(Earnings_Year$Month_USD)],
    y=Earnings_Year$Month_USD[which.max(Earnings_Year$Month_USD)],
    text = "Last Teaching Job in China") %>% 
  add_annotations(
    x=Earnings_Year$Year[Earnings_Year$Year==2006],
    y=Earnings_Year$Month_USD[Earnings_Year$Month_USD==1160],
    text="First Job"
  ) %>% 
  add_annotations(
    x=Earnings_Year$Year[Earnings_Year$Year==2021],
    y=Earnings_Year$Month_USD[Earnings_Year$Month_USD==2300],
    text="Began Ph.D.") %>% 
  add_annotations(
    x=Earnings_Year$Year[Earnings_Year$Year==2008],
    y=Earnings_Year$Month_USD[Earnings_Year$Month_USD==1360],
    text="Finished H.S.") %>% 
  add_annotations(
    x=Earnings_Year$Year[Earnings_Year$Year==2015],
    y=Earnings_Year$Month_USD[Earnings_Year$Month_USD==2000],
    text="Finished BA") %>% 
  layout(legend= list(x=1,y=0.5),
         title="Earnings by Degree",
         xaxis=list(title="Year"),
         yaxis=list(title="Monthly USD"))
```

Finished Product:

[image: Finished]